# Redirect after login to a tab bar controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, storyboard, uitabbar

in a project, I have a login system. If the login is accepted I put this piece of code to redirect to the first page.

```
  let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){ action in

                        if let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DashboardViewController") as? DashboardViewController{

                            if let navigator = self.navigationController {
                                navigator.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
                            }
                        }


                    }



                    myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                    self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
```

everything works but now on my first page "DashboardViewController"
I have added one. tab bar controller.

[image]

if I redirect to page 1 the tab bar controller is not taken into account but if I start my project by tab bar controller everything works. so my question is how to redirect to tab bar controller after my login

Comment: Currently how are you redirecting to tabBarController ?

Comment: yes, in fact I want to always redirect to the first page but that the tabbar is taken into account

Comment: have you tried with tabBarVC.selectedIndex = // your selected index 
at the time of redirection to tabbarController?

Comment: Are you instantiate tab bar controller by identifier after you added it to storyboard? (this line - if let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DashboardViewController") as? DashboardViewController)

Comment: no, i saw another topic that speaks about tabBarVC but i do not know how to redirect

Comment: @Kenpachi please share the code of how you redirecting to tabBarController ?

Comment: @tema.orange je ne crois pas
I have no code to redirect to bar bar just, I know just redirect to my first page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect to tabbarController like

```
    let tabBarController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: tabBarControllerIdentifier)
    if let navigator = self.navigationController {
         navigator.pushViewController(tabBarController, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let tabBarVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarVC") as! TabBarVC
    tabBarVC.selectedIndex = //your selected tab index
    navigationController?.pushViewController(tabBarVC, animated: true)
```

Dont redirect dashboardVC go with tabbarVC and then select tabIndex that you want your first page

Comment: use of undeclared type tabBarVc
I must add something?

Comment: yes you have to add your identifier like, TabBarVC instead of  DashboardViewController

Comment: can I send you a link with the project and you show me an example?

Comment: i can not share project for example but if u have face any problem surely give solution have you any problem in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I handled it slightly differently.

```
 func transitionToHome() {

    let tabBarViewController = UIStoryboard(name: Constants.Storyboard.mainStoryBoard, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.Storyboard.tabBarController) as! UITabBarController

      view.window?.rootViewController = tabBarViewController
      view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

}
```

I am reassigning the tabBarController to be the root view so that the user can return without having to log in again. I also use a constant file to keep my constants organized for complex projects. You can see how I reference them in the code above.

```
struct Constants {

struct Storyboard {

    static let homeViewController = "HomeVC"

    static let tabBarController = "HomeTVC"

    static let mainStoryBoard = "Main"
}
```

}